# Python Glob without the whole path - only the filename

Tags: python, glob

Is there a way I can use glob on a directory, to get files with a specific extension, but only the filename itself, not the whole path?

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Use [`os.path.basename(path)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) to get the filename.

Comment: This is not exactly the same as relative glob though. Imagine the pattern is `"sql/*.sql"`. The `os.listdir` function would actually list file paths relative to the given directory, though it does not work with patterns. EDIT: Ah, I was looking for this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44994860/1317713 The trick is using `os.path.relpath` rather than `basename`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. How to get rid the extension part..such as .csv, .dat, .nc, etc

Answer (score 186):

This might help someone:

`names = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob('/your_path')]`

Comment: Alternatively they would use [os.path.relpath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath) instead of [os.path.basename](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) if they want a relative path to `'/your_path'` rather than just the filename.

Comment: relpath or just `old = os.getcwd(); os.chdir(dir); files = glob.glob('**/*.txt'); os.chdir(old)`

Answer (score 19):

```py
map(os.path.basename, glob.glob("your/path"))
```

Returns an iterable with all the file names and extensions.

Answer (score 5):

os.path.basename works for me.

**Here is Code example:**

```
import sys,glob
import os

expectedDir = sys.argv[1]                                                    ## User input for directory where files to search

for fileName_relative in glob.glob(expectedDir+"**/*.txt",recursive=True):       ## first get full file name with directores using for loop

    print("Full file name with directories: ", fileName_relative)

    fileName_absolute = os.path.basename(fileName_relative)                 ## Now get the file name with os.path.basename

    print("Only file name: ", fileName_absolute)
```

**Output :**

```
Full file name with directories:  C:\Users\erinksh\PycharmProjects\EMM_Test2\venv\Lib\site-packages\wheel-0.33.6.dist-info\top_level.txt
Only file name:  top_level.txt
```

Comment: You have mixed up your variable names: absolute means full path; relative means only the base name.

Answer (score 5):

Or using pathlib:

```
from pathlib import Path

dir_URL = Path("your_directory_URL") # e.g. Path("/tmp")
filename_list = [file.name for file in dir_URL.glob("your_pattern")]
```

Answer (score 3):

I keep rewriting the solution for [relative globbing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44994604/python-glob-os-relative-path-making-filenames-into-a-list) (esp. when I need to add items to a zipfile) - this is what it usually ends up looking like.

```py
# Function
def rel_glob(pattern, rel):
    """glob.glob but with relative path
    """
    for v in glob.glob(os.path.join(rel, pattern)):
        yield v[len(rel):].lstrip("/")

# Use
# For example, when you have files like: 'dir1/dir2/*.py'
for p in rel_glob("dir2/*.py", "dir1"):
    # do work
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for CSV file:

```
file = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\rajat.prakash\Downloads//' + '*.csv')]
```

If you are looking for EXCEL file:

```
file = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\rajat.prakash\Downloads//' + '*.xlsx')]
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the existing answers mention using the new [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module, which is what I was searching for, so I'll add a new answer here.

[`Path.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) produces `Path` objects containing the full path including any directories.  If you only need the file names, use the [`Path.name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name) property.

---

If you find yourself frequently converting between `pathlib` and [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html), check out [this handy table converting functions between the two libraries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#correspondence-to-tools-in-the-os-module).

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in glob.glob(gt_path + "/*.png"):  # find all png files
      exc_name = f.split('/')[-1].split(',')[0]
```

Then the `exc_name` is like `myphoto.png`

Answer (score 1):

Use glob.glob("*.filetype") to get a list of all files with complete path and use os.path.basename(list_item) to remove the extra path and retain only the filename.

Here is an example:

```
import glob
a=glob.glob("*.pkl")
```

It returns a list with the complete path of each file ending with .pkl

Now you can remove the path information and extract only the filename for an list item using:

```
import os
b=os.path.basename(a[0]) 
# This is an example to extract filename for only one list item
```

If you need to create an entire list with only the filename:

```
bb=[os.path.basename(list_item) for list_item in a]
```