# Python glob, os, relative path, making filenames into a list

Tags: python, linux, macos

I am trying to make a list of all files in a directory with filenames in a that end in .root.

After reading some writings in the forum I tried to basic strategies using glob and os.listdir but I got into trouble for both of them

First, when I use

```
import glob
filelist = glob.glob('/home/usr/dir/*.root')
```

It does make a list of string with all filenames that end in .root but I still face a problem.

I would like to be the list of string to have filenames as '/dir/*.root' but the string has full path '/home/usr/dir/*.root'

Second, if I use os.listdir, I get into the trouble that

```
  path = '/home/usr/'
  filelist = os.listdir(path + 'dir/*.root')
  syntax error
```

which tells me that I can not only get the list of files for .root.

In summary, I would like to make a list of filenames, that end in .root and are in my /home/usr/dir, while cutting off the '/home/usr' part. If I use globe, I get into the trouble of having /home/usr/. If I use os.listdir, I can't specify ".root" endling.

Comment: If you want filepaths to be relative, you must first decide relative to what. To the current working directory? To a specific directory?

Comment: I left a simple and concise function for relative globbing over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57514353/790075

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`glob` will return paths in a format matching your query, so that

```
glob.glob("/home/usr/dir/*.root")
# ['home/usr/dir/foo.root', 'home/usr/dir/bar.root', ...]

glob.glob("*.root")
# ['foo.root', 'bar.root', ...]

glob.glob("./*.root")
# ['./foo.root', './bar.root', ...]
```

...and so forth.

To get only the filename, you can use `path.basename` of the [`os`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) module, something like this:

```
from glob import glob
from os import path

pattern = "/home/usr/dir/*.root"
files = [path.basename(x) for x in glob(pattern)]
# ['foo.root', 'bar.root', ...]
```

...or, if you want to prepend the `dir` part:

```
pattern = "/home/usr/dir/*.root"
files = [path.join('dir', path.basename(x)) for x in glob(pattern)]
# ['dir/foo.root', 'dir/bar.root', ...]
```

...or, if you really want the path separator at the start:

```
from glob import glob
import os

pattern = "/home/usr/dir/*.root"
files = [os.sep + os.path.join('dir', os.path.basename(x)) for x in glob(pattern)]
# ['/dir/foo.root', '/dir/bar.root', ...]
```

Using `path.join` and `path.sep` will make sure that the correct path syntax is used, depending on your OS (i.e. `/` or `\` as a separator).

Depending on what you are really trying to do here, you might want to look at `os.path.relpath`, for the relative path. The title of your question indicates that relative paths might be what you are actually after:

```
pattern = "/home/usr/dir/*.root"
files = [os.path.relpath(x) for x in glob(pattern)]
# files will now contain the relative path to each file, from the current working directory
```

Answer (score 6):

just use `glob` for getting the list you want
and then use  `os.path.relpath` on each file

```
import glob
files_names = []
for file in glob.glob('/home/usr/dir/*.root'):
    files_names.append(os.path.relpath(file, "/home/usr"))
```

You can also use regex

```
import re
files_names.append(re.sub(r'//home//usr//','', file, flags=re.I))
```

Comment: Using the regex as suggested here should be avoided, because it's not portable. (Consider the "Windows-style" paths.)
Favor the path manipulation features of Python.